# Addressing an argument in bash

Tags: bash

If I'm sending a list of strings as an argument to script_help or to a function.
And I want to address is, when I'm trying to write ${$1[*]}
I was told $num address to the the #num argument that was passed on to the script/function. 
How can I fix it ?
Notice im not allowed to use the "for each" form
For example :
In the main script :

```
List_a=(a b c)
List_b=(d e)
Help_script $list_a $list_b
```

And in the help script :

```
For str1 in ${$1[*]};do
  #commands
Done 
For str2 in ${$2[*]};do 
  #commands
Done
```

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example? It's not clear from your description what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes , for example:I'm trying to send two lists of strings to a script , and checking each string with for loop . so I'm trying to address the first list, for Str in ${$1[*]}

Comment: That's not a concrete example. Please edit your question to show an *exact* example of how you are calling your script.

Comment: You aren't passing two "lists" to `Help_script`. You are passing five arguments. See what `echo $#` outputs in `Help_script` also what `printf '[%s]\n' "$@"` does. You can't pass arrays to functions directly. Only by name/etc.

Comment: Got it. Thank you guys